# Jacoco code coverage report is wrong?

Tags: java, junit4, jacoco

I configured jacoco in maven `pom.xml` for code coverage and excluded some classes in `pom.xml`. When i excluded particular package code, coverage percentage is increased from 64% to 88% (because of exclusion). But overall project code coverage percentage is same before and after exclusion.

Please suggest me how to get actual code coverage results.

Comment: have you checked the jacoco documentation? point of thought: excluding classes doesn't give higher coverage, it just makes some people believe it does. It might be that the overall coverage is based on all the classes, not just the ones you want to be covered

Comment: Then: are you using poweermock? That gives wrong results, too.

Comment: Then i am not able to understand what is use of excluding of some classes . Here i do not want to write the junit test cases for some classes which i want to exclude from code coverage !!!!!!!

Comment: @GhostCat,  Here we are using BDDMocito.

Comment: JaCoCo calculates total and not-covered instructions, branches, lines, methods, classes along with percentage. None of them changed on project level? There is no such term as "overall" in JaCoCo report (http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/counters.html), so what does it mean in your question? In a lack of details in your question (screenshots before/after, absence of [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), can only guess what's wrong in your case and say that exclusions are working and reports are correct.

Comment: Moreover - why do you expect total to change? Not even taking into account rounding during calculation of percentage - here is simple mathematical example: two classes with 5 covered and 10 instructions in total, exclusion of one does not change percentage that is 50% = 5 / 10 = (5 + 5) / (10 + 10)

Comment: here overall means total project code coverage and not able to see the increment of coverage even if some classes are excluded.